# How to Auto Update date in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

On button click I want documents to be printed each with a new date for all months in Cell A2.

The code below only updates the date once and the first date is the current date.

When I click on the button, cell A2 needs to be filled with the first date of the month and then this document should be printed.
Once this document is printed cell A2 needs to be updated with the next date and the document again needs to be printed with the updated date.
This continues until the month of December.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Range("A2").Value = Format(Date, "dd MMMM yy")

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, collate:=True

Range("A2").Value = Range("A2").Value + 1

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, collate:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: "On button click I want documents to be printed each with a new date for all months in Cell A2" does not make sense. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: When I click on the button, cell A2 need to be filled with the first date of the month and then this document should be printed. Once this document is printed cell A2 needs to be updated with the next date and the document again needs to be printed with the updated date. This continues until the month of December. Does this makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next updated code. It firstly print the sheet with **first day of the current month** and second time with the last:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim firstD As Date, lastD As Date
 
 firstD = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
 lastD = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0)

 Range("A2").Value = Format(firstD, "dd MMMM yy")
 ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, collate:=True

 Range("A2").Value = Format(lastD, "dd MMMM yy")
 ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, collate:=True
End Sub
```

Is this what you want/need?

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version which should do what (I understood) you need:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim d As Date, curYear As Long
   
   d = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1) 'initial day
   curYear  = Year(d)

   Do While Year(d) = curYear And Month(d) <= 12 And Day(d) <= 31
        Range("A2").Value = Format(d, "dd MMMM yy")
        
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, collate:=True
        
        d = d + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I need all the dates from the first day of the month to the last day of the month to be printed.  From the current month to the last month of the year.

Comment: @Melissa Dmello Your question is very foggy... Even now, I cannot dare to work something else, even if what you say looks clear, no offence. I need you to confirm that my understanding is correct: So do you want the code printing 9 times, for remaining days of September and then other 31 + 30 + 31 times for each day of the following months? Or 30 times for the current month and 31 + 30 + 31 for the following months?

Comment: The second. 30 times for the current month and 31 + 30 + 31 for the following months.

Comment: @Melissa Dmello Then, please try the version posted after **Edited** and send some feedback.

Comment: @Melissa Dmello Glad I (finally) could help! But you must learn something from this question, I think: 1. Asking properly you increase your chance to receive a good answer. In order to receive help, you firstly must help us understanding what you try accomplishing. 2. We here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, thick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. If more answers, you should choose the one looking more suitable against your need. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the suggested solutions works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the worksheet function **EOMONTH** to calculate the last day of the previous month.  Then add 1 to the date to advance it to the start of the current month.

There are two options detailed below.

1. Loop through the current month by day
2. Loop through to an arbitrary date by day

Option 2 is commented out.  To use it comment out Option 1 and uncomment Option 2.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim StartOfMonth As Date
Dim DateStep As Long
Dim DayCounter As Long

    StartOfMonth = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1)
'Calculate the last date of the prior month

    DateStep = Day(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0))
'Calculate the last day of the current month (Option 1)

'   DateStep = DateSerial(2022, 12, 31) - StartOfMonth
'Alternate for a longer date range instead of the current month (Option 2)

    For DayCounter = 1 To DateStep
    
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = Format(StartOfMonth + DayCounter, "dd MMMM yy")
    'Insert the date into a cell
    
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, collate:=True
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You ! I already tried the code above by @FaneDure